# Enum Is Defined not giving value from Index

Tags: c#, .net, enums, enumeration, tryparse

Dear Friends,

```
 public enum Units
    {
      Meter = 0,
      Centimeter = 1,
      Milimeter = 2
    }
    
    unitEnumStringOrIndex = "Meter"; //Working
    unitEnumStringOrIndex = "1";// Not working
    
    if(Enum.TryParse<Units>(unitEnumStringOrIndex, true, out Units unitEnum))
    {
      if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Units), unitEnumStringOrIndex))
        {
           return true;
        }else {
           return false;
        }
     }else {
      return false;
     }
```

I am having a strange problem as you can see from the above example. We have an enum type and we want to make sure that enum value exists.so for that I have read in Microsoft documentation that we can use IsDefined method to ensure existence.
I implemented that and I can see that it returns the correct value when we pass the "Meter" string but similar way if I pass the "1" then it does not return true. So I do not return me the value Centimeter as expecting.
Any lead will be appreciating.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working just fine, only not as you're expecting.

The `TryParse` method will succeed to parse the value whether it's a string containing the name of one of the `enum`'s members, or a string that can be parsed as the value of one of the `enum` members.

[From official documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__)

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object. The return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

This means that when you try parse the string `"Meter"` the result is `Units.Meter`, but when you try parse the string `"1"` the result is `Units.Centimeter`.

The [`IsDefined`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netcore-3.1) method is documented as follows:

> Returns a Boolean telling whether a given integral value, or its name as a string, exists in a specified enumeration.

This means that if you feed it with `"1"` or `1` it does different things - the string does not match the *name* of any of the `enum` members and therefor `IsDefined` returns `false`, however the int does match the *value* of one of the `enum` members and therefor `IsDefined` returns `true`.

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>rextester.</kbd>](https://rextester.com/TIIQ35539)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are looking to get the enum name by the value, so you can do like this.

```
int val = 1;
Units enumValue = (Units)val;
string stringName = enumValue.ToString(); //Centimeter
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing index number as `stirng`, you should pass it as `int`.

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Units), 1)) //true
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Units), "1")) //false
```

Comment: See online working code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GCdRcw)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you use `unitEnumStringOrIndex = "1";` unitEnum gets the value 'Centimeter' as expected.
The problem lies with Enum.IDefined: this expects an object which is either the name as a string or the value **as an integer**. Since you are passing a string ("1"), 'IsDefined' looks for the name "1" which does not exist in your enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to check wether *text string* or *integer string* values:

```
static void Test()
{
  var values = new string[]
  {
    "Meter",
    "1",
    "Meterr",
    "10"
  };
  foreach ( string value in values )
    Console.WriteLine(IsUnitsNameOrValue(value));
}

static public bool IsUnitsNameOrValue(string value)
{
  if ( int.TryParse(value, out int valueInt) )
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Units), valueInt);
  else
    return Enum.TryParse(value, true, out Units unitEnum);
}
```

*Result*

```
True
True
False
False
```

Comment: @All : I found my mistake just need to pass the unitEnum as it gives already converted integer value.Now its working fine.
Thanks to all members for their suggestion and examples.
So i marked this as resolved.